# Rake Tasks in Ruby on Rails are stopped once terminal session connection dies

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, amazon-ec2, web-scraping, rake-task

I use a normal SSH terminal to run rake tasks (such as web scraping) in my /myapp/lib/tasks/ folder. The code is in the cloud on Amazon EC2 servers.

The rake task runs fine but let's say if my computer shuts down, then the SSH terminal session dies too, then the rake task seems to end - when it should be continually running all day.

What can I do to keep it from stopping?

Comment: Use something like Cron

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do the tasks in terminal with your account then it is connected to the current session. I'd suggest either running them by daemon on putting them to the background. In linux you detach processes by adding & to the end of command.

Take a look at answers here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/8653/how-to-keep-processes-running-after-ending-ssh-session